# Which Okta event should I use when a user is unassigned from an application

Tags: single-sign-on, okta

I am using `Okta` for `SSO` and I want to receive an `event webhook` for when a user is assigned, deleted, removed from an application.

The Okta documentation says there's 2 types of hooks (`asynchronous and synchronous`).

I think `synchronous, inline hooks` are better because if my backend app doesn't process the event correctly, then I do not want the user to be removed on the Okta side.

Which `inline event hook type` should I use to know when a user is removed/unassigned from an application?

Documentation I have looked at so far:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/07/20/easy-user-sync-hooks
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/event-types/#catalog
https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/event-hooks/#sample-event-delivery-payload
https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/inline-hooks/
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/hooks/#get-started

Answer (score 1):

Sync hooks exist only for certain events, so you can't just choose for any given event which hook you want to use. If I'm correct application unassignment is not the one covered by inline hooks, so you are left only with async one.
You can read more about inline ones in [Okta documentation](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/inline-hooks/#currently-supported-types)